# Trying to destroy an iframe html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script that creates an iframe to run a websocket server with a better gui, the idea being you can start the server through it. However it creates the iframe but when I remove in using .html("") I can no longer see it but it still runs - how can I fully close it. As a bit of background I'm doing it this way as I don't have access to shell on cPanel so I'm running it through this.

Thanks.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function server_load() {
    $('#server_console').html('<iframe src="server.php" width="700px" height="500px" frameborder="0" id="myFrame"></iframe>');
    $('#status').html('Online');
    $('#status').css('background-color', '#2E7D32');
    $('#status').attr('onclick', 'server_halt();')

}

function server_halt() {
    $('#server_console').html('');
    $('#status').html('Offline');
    $('#status').css('background-color', '#C62828');
    $('#status').attr('onclick', 'server_load();')
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="server_container">
    <button id="status" onclick="server_load();">Offline</button>
    <div id="server_console"></div>


</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried using $('#server_console').remove(); rather than $('#server_console').html('');

Comment: try remove -- https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: I don't want to remove the element in it's entirety but I will give it a try

Comment: Why don't you set the location of the iframe to something like about:blank?

Comment: I've just tested .remove and that didn't solver the issue, neither did about:blank unfourtunately